# pysnmp 4.2.5 sending trap with object fails in sendPdu

Tags: python, snmp, mib, pysnmp

so I'm trying to get traps working in our project. We are using a custom mib and walking it already works, also sending traps without additional data works fine with the following code and the OBJECT property removed from the trap in the MIB:

```
def sendEventTrap(self, event):
    if(doPrintTraps):
        print "Sending trap"
    ntfOrg = ntforg.NotificationOriginator(self._snmpContext)
    errorIndication = ntfOrg.sendNotification(
        self._snmpEngine,
        'trap',
        ('PROJECT-MIB', 'eventTrap'),
        ())
```

Now I'm trying to add a simple Integer32 additional object like so

```
def sendEventTrap(self, event):
    if(doPrintTraps):
        print "Sending trap"
    ntfOrg = ntforg.NotificationOriginator(self._snmpContext)
    errorIndication = ntfOrg.sendNotification(
        self._snmpEngine,
        'trap',
        ('PROJECT-MIB', 'eventTrap'),
        [((1, 3, 6, 1, 4, 1, 999999, 3, 1, 0) , v2c.Integer32(1337))])
```

However this fails even though according to the following log it does find and match the right OID with the correctly associated Integer32 type: http://pastebin.com/hJ9LAiAg

This is the relevant part of the MIB:

```
eventNotifications OBJECT IDENTIFIER ::= { xxx 4 }

eventTrap NOTIFICATION-TYPE
    OBJECTS     { direction }
    STATUS current
    DESCRIPTION ""
::= {eventNotifications 1}
```

NOTE some function names have been changed for privacy reasons.
I'm at a loss here and would greatly appreciate inputs as to where things are going wrong.

Comment: I imagine is would be much easier to troubleshoot this issue if you were using pysnmp 4.3. Besides cleaner design, it has many bugs fixed. Other  than that, make sure you have snmpEngine object local to each thread -- all states are kept at snmpEngine object and there is no inner locking performed.

Comment: Sadly version 4.2.5 is what debian stable provides as it's distribution package, which I'd prefer to stick to. Is it source compatible though, at least for the native API? Thanks for the snmpEngine threading tip I'll have to check that out.

Comment: pysnmp 4.3  is API-compatible with pysnmp 4.2.5 (for all 4.2.5 interfaces). Speaking of your code snippet, it looks like the exception you see occurs in exception handler while handling exception raised by sendPdu(). It is therefore hard to tell what was the cause of original exception. If you enable more pysnmp debugging chances are the original exception shows up there...

Comment: Ok so what I found out is that I can get attaching varBinds to work if I don't add the OBJECTS { direction } directive. It seems that's because that parameter really is for _additional_ varBinds only. However I'd expect to automatically send the correct object if OBJECTS is specified, which doesn't work. But anyway this is good enough for me at the moment. So thanks for your input, turning up the logging really helped.

Comment: @IlyaEtingof I'm finally looking into this again because albeit it works without having the trap's VarBind in the MIB it would be much better documented if it were. I tried again with PySNMP 4.3.2 and now I'm getting the following exception in PySNMP
http://pastebin.com/cchsQwtK

Answer (score 1):

I finally got this working. There were actually two problems.

1. This functionality seems to be broken in 4.2.5 where my current code still fails with a key error. On 4.3.2 it works well.
2. The code above is missing `instanceIndex=(0,)` as a parameter and when sending an already managed object one doesn't have to include it as a varBind by hand.

The following works with the declarations as in the questions MIB:

```
ntfOrg = ntforg.NotificationOriginator(self._snmpContext)
errorIndication = ntfOrg.sendNotification(
    self._snmpEngine,
    'trap',
    ('PROJECT-MIB', 'eventTrap'),
    instanceIndex=(0,))
```